# Facebook open graph give error "Unable to Generate Story" while creating stories

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am creating stories in Facebook open graph but it shows error "Unable to Generate Story", before august it was working perfectly. Any one knows why its not working?

Comment: I have also created a story yesterday, but i keep getting text in red saying "unable to generate story". Please post if you get any solution for the same, I will do the same

Comment: We are seeing the same. Just curious. Are there more than one language involved in your cases? Trying to figure out if it is related to that. In our cases, it started happening after we added the second language.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create sample objects and actions.
2. Debug using object debugger.